# Incorrect argument label in call (have 'named:', expected 'systemName:')

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to show the contents of the collection view through search. However, there are many errors while binding collection views. I think the model code got weird first, where is it weird? How can we fix this error?

```
 output.loadData.map(CollectionOfOne.init).bind(to: collectionView.rx.items) { (row,collectionView, element) -> UICollectionViewCell in
            let indexPath = IndexPath(index: 1)
            guard let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "friendCell", for: indexPath) as? FriendCell else {
                return FriendCell()
            }
            cell.profileImage?.image = UIImage(systemName: element.image)
            cell.nickNameLbl?.text = element.nickname
            cell.listenBtn?.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: {[unowned self] in
                selectIndexPath.accept(row)
            }).disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
    
            return cell
        }
 output.searchNameResult.map(CollectionOfOne.init).bind(to: collectionView.rx.items) { collectionView, index, element -> UICollectionViewCell in
            let indexPath = IndexPath(index: 0)
            guard let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "freindCell", for: indexPath) as? FriendCell else {
                return FriendCell()
            }
         //   cell.profileImage?.image = UIImage(systemName: (element as AnyObject).image)
            cell.profileImage?.image = UIImage(named: element.img)
            cell.nickNameLbl?.text = (element.nickname)
            
            return cell
        }
```

This is viewcontroller code

```
struct input {
        let loadData: Signal<Void>
        let searchName: Driver<Void>
        let searchHashTag: Driver<Void>
    }

    struct output {
        let loadData: BehaviorRelay<[User]>
        let searchNameResult: PublishRelay<users>
    }
func transform(_ input: input) -> output {
        let api = SearchAPI()
        let loadData = BehaviorRelay<[User]>(value: [])
        let searchName = PublishRelay<users>()

        input.loadData.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self]  in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            api.getFriend().subscribe(onNext: { (response, statuscode) in
                switch statuscode {
                case .ok:
             //       loadData.accept(response!, User)
                    result.onCompleted()
                default:
                    result.onNext("default")
                }
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        input.searchName.asObservable().withLatestFrom(input.name).subscribe(onNext: {[weak self] nickname in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            api.getUserList(nickname).subscribe(onNext: { (response,statuscode) in
                switch statuscode {
                case .ok:
                    result.onCompleted()
                case .noHere:
                    result.onNext("no user")
                default:
                    result.onNext("default")
                }
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And this is my viewmodel.
What is the problem?

Comment: "there are many errors while binding collection views" please clarify what kind of errors and where exactly do you see them. Also what is "element.img", what is "users" ? The code you provided looks insufficient to determine the problem

Comment: Users are models and element.img is importing images.Errors are occurring in all codes starting with cell. ``` struct users: Codable {
    let users: [searchUser]
}

struct searchUser: Codable {
    let email: String
    let nickname: String
    let img: String
    let listening: Int
    let listener: Int
    let isListening: Bool
}
``` This is model

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not enough. Please edit your question with code that can be reproduced. And specify what errors are you receiving.

Comment: Do you really have a struct called `users` in your code?

Comment: What is `input.name`? I don't see a `name` on your `Input` struct.

Comment: Where is `result` defined? It can't be part of `self`, is it really a global?

Comment: Why are you calling `.map(CollectionOfOne.init)`? That doesn't make much sense there.

Comment: @ Daniel T. users is model. struct users: Codable {
    let users: [searchUser]
}

struct searchUser: Codable {
    let email: String
    let nickname: String
    let img: String
    let listening: Int
    let listener: Int
    let isListening: Bool
}

Comment: @earth update the question with this info.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the error: `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'named:', expected 'systemName:')` because of this other error: `Value of type 'users' has no member 'img'`.

I expect that you don't really want to display a single cell but the code is so muddled in general that it's hard to make out exactly what you are trying to do. I suggest you find yourself a tutor who can teach you about types, or possibly use the [Swift Playgrounds](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/swift-playgrounds/id1496833156?mt=12) app to learn the basics of how to code before you try to make a real program.